# Keeping all columns when using ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I have a `ddplay` function which looks like this

```
myF <- ddply(.data = someDf,
                  .variables = ~X,
                  .fun = function(piece) {
                      as.Date(piece$myDate, "%d.%m.%Y") %>% which.min
})
```

I need my whole dataframe to be returned, not just a dataframe with the variables `X`, `Y` and `myDate`. How can I tell `ddply` that its supposed to sort my data as the function says, but return every column of my initial df?

My df where I run the operation on looks like

```
X    Y    c    d    myDate    
a1   12   bb   c    05.05.12
a1   14   cd   a    04.05.12
b1   12   ff   r    10.12.15
c1   15   ss   g    09.09.10
b1   12   aa   p    01.02.12
```

After the ddply its supposed to look like this

```
X    Y    c    d    myDate    
a1   14   cd   a    04.05.12
c1   15   ss   g    09.09.10
b1   12   aa   p    01.02.12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar answer to @bramtayl, but also using a filter.

```
> library(dplyr)

> new_df <- x %>%
+  group_by(X) %>%
+  mutate(myDate = as.Date(myDate, format = '%d.%m.%y')) %>%
+  filter(myDate == min(myDate))

> new_df
Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
Groups: X [3]

       X      Y      c      d     myDate
  (fctr) (fctr) (fctr) (fctr)     (date)
1     a1     14     cd      a 2012-05-04
2     c1     15     ss      g 2010-09-09
3     b1     12     aa      p 2012-02-01

> unique(x$X) %>% length == nrow(new_df)
[1] TRUE

> unique(x$X) %>% length == length(new_df)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: That seems to work. However, when I run `unique(x$X) %>% length` the length of that result is way different than the length of the `df` returned by your code. That shouldnt be.

Comment: I believe you are incorrectly using `length` here.  If you are using `length(new_df)`, you are returning the number of columns in your data frame...which is wrong.  You want `nrow(new_df)`.  That should be the same and it is the same on the data you provided.

Comment: `unique` does not give me a `df` back, but a vector! So `length` should be ok.

Comment: I compared `unique(x$X) %>% length` with `nrow(new_df)`. But, my `unique(x$X) %>% length` is 16030 and my `nrow(new_df)` is 42540. Any ideas what might be the problem here?!

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about it, **assuming your output is the same length as your input**:

```
myF <- cbind( myF, 
                  ddply(.data = someDf,
                  .variables = ~X+Y,
                  .fun = function(piece) {
                      as.Date(piece$myDate, "%d.%m.%Y") %>% which.min
})
)
```

This will append the new information into a column at the end of your data frame.

Comment: My output is not the same length. Thats sort of the point of `ddply` isnt it? :)

Comment: It depends :) can you `dput()` your data so we can see what you're working with?

Comment: I added a schematic example of my dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(X) %>%
  slice(myDate %>% 
          as.Date("%d.%m.%Y") %>% 
          which.min %>% 
          last)
```

Comment: Nope. When I run `unique(x$X) %>% length` the length of that result is way different than the length of the df returned by your code. That shouldnt be